# Como fazer requisições Ajax em Java

Tags: java, ajax, aplicação-web, servlet

Bom Dia

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Web onde preciso de algo simples: quando o usuário seleciona um estado em um *ComboBox*, o sistema deve atualizar outro *ComboBox* com todas as cidades.

Sou programador .NET e neste modelo eu usaria um esquema com *UpdatePanels* e *Triggers* para realizar essa ação sem recarregar a página inteira. Contudo, a aplicação que estou desenvolvendo agora precisa ser em Java e mesmo pesquisando não consegui entender direito o funcionamento do Ajax nesta linguagem.

Preciso de um exemplo mais prático e exato para conseguir fazer isso funcionar.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: está trabalhando com jsf? Se sim, qual versão?

Comment: O Ajax funciona em JavaScript. o Java você idealmente faria tudo REST. Logo, não deveria haver qualquer coisa sobre Ajax no seu código Java. Exceto, é claro, se você estiver utilizando um framework que produz também todo o CSS, Javascript e/ou HTML, especialmente se for lguma coisa que não seja REST, mas aí você teria que dizer que framework é esse.

Comment: Acho que acabei não sendo muito claro Victor, eu não queria colocar o Ajax dentro do Java, apenas entender como funcionam as chamadas para um código Java pois tenho mais conhecimento em ASP.NET e nessa linguagem eu uso outro método para fazer esse tipo de requisição. De qualquer forma, já consegui resolver. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso do java, basta fazer a requisição via Ajax para um endereço que fará o processamento. O idela é requisitar uma Servlet.
Dentro dessa servlet, vc faria o processamento e o retorno dela, seria esse seu outro combobox.

**Exemplo básico:**

*Primeiro a requisição via Ajax:*

```
function getComboBox() {
    var xhttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //code for modern browsers
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for old IE browsers
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 3) {
            console.log("Processando");
        } 
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("seuSelectID").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          console.log("Pronto");
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "/SuaAplicacao/SuaServlet.java", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("action=filtrar&idEstado=1"); // Exemplo de passagem de parametros.
}
```

*A Servlet:*

```
    // imports omitidos

    @WebServlet("/ajaxservlet")
    public class AjaxServlet extends HttpServlet {

       protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
           String action = "";
           // action foi passado pelo ajax
           if(request.getParameter("action") != null && request.getParameter("action".equals("filtrar")) {

             // aqui vc faz a busca usando os métodos de sua aplicação. O id foi passado pelo ajax.
             List<SeuObjetoCidade> lista = SeuDAO.listaCidadesByIdDoEstado(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("idEstado")));

             // Este objeto, será o retorno que o ajax utilizará no this.responseText
             PrintWriter pw =  response.getWriter();
             for(SeuObjetoCidade obj: lista) {
                pw.println("<option value='"+obj.getId()+"'>");
                pw.println(obj.getNome());
                pw.println("</option>");
             }
             pw.close();
           }

       }
    }
```

Acima é só um exemplo, como citei. Existe várias formas de fazer isso, passando JSON como retorno e tudo mais.

Outro ponto, caso queira algum framework para ajudar nessa questão Java / Ajax, pesquise pelo **DWR**.

Comment: Muito obrigado Maycon, sua explicação foi clara e concisa. Consegui fazer meu código funcionar e agora sim entendi como a funciona. Apenas um adendo, você está passando uma variável 'idEstado' no JS e pegando uma variável 'id' no Java, tive que corrigir isso no meu código.

Comment: Bem observado Matheus! Fiz a alteração para melhor entendimento.